# How can I preserve the timestamp of a file that I upload (mput) with /usr/bin/ftp?

Tags: linux, ftp, timestamp

I am using `/usr/bin/ftp` to upload a file into an FTP server with `mput` command.

The timestamp is not preserved. The uploaded file always has the timestamp of the current time, when I uploaded the file.

Comment: The common Linux commandline `ftp` does not support preserving timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable that contains the current timestamp:

```
mystamp=$(date -r  "/home/usr/MYFILE.TXT" "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
```

Then send it to the `ftp`:

```
/usr/bin/ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASSWORD
cd $remote
lcd $localdir
mput MYFILE.txt
site "UTIME $mystamp MYFILE.txt"
bye
EOF
```